# Using Google Web Designer, Sencha Animator, or Hype to create interactive storybook and convert to iOS or Android using PhoneGap

Tags: html, extjs, cordova

I am thinking of creating some storybooks and was looking at many solutions. Such as:

- Moglue
- iBooks
- Corona

But then I thought why not use HTML5 and Google Web Designer or Sencha Animator or Hype instead. Hoping someone has worked with these products and and give some tips on which of these products support:

1. How's SVG image support? If I use SVG images, would they work with PhoneGap to convert to iOS or Android?
2. Working with sound files. So lets say I have background and a bunch of different balloons.. I like to have each balloon say a specific phrase when clicked. Would that be easy to do? And how does it convert when trying to convert this to native app using PhoneGap?

Any sample projects out there with source code that's HTML5 and a storybook like format?

Thanks for any suggestions or tips.